# Network port open, but no process attached?

Tags: linux, networking, nagios, netstat, opsview

I have a weird situation going on with an open network port. My main question is, why would there not be a program associated with an open TCP port:

```
netstat -ln --program
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

For my specific case, there is supposed to be an nrpe daemon (opsview install) listening on port 5666, but there is no nrpe daemon running. If I try to start it, it exits immediately.

`lsof -i :5666` doesn't show any output either. There is no (x)inetd running on my system.

*UPDATE*

Yes, I was running those commands as root. Telnet would could, but there was never any response.

After further investigation, I found a kernel error in `dmesg`: this was an EC2 instance (actually several of them) running an older kernel (2.6.16 is apparently unstable). The fix to stop the crash was to [upgrade kernels](http://www.vincestross.com/2009/04/upgrade-an-ec2-instance/).

It looks like the way the kernel crashed caused the process to go away and leave the port open.

Comment: What is the result of: lsof -i tcp:5666? Does the port stay there when you reboot?

Comment: Is this a new install of NRPE?

Comment: You need to run netstat as root to see program details

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your own questions...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ports open by the kernel won't show up with program name. Some NFS and OCFS stuff come to mind. Maybe it's something like that?

Or it could be a kernel bug. Check kernel logs for OOPS and BUG.

Answer (score 36):

Have you run netstat and lsof as root or with sudo? Notice the last column:

```
netstat -ln --program
tcp        0      0 192.168.21.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

sudo netstat -ln --program
tcp        0      0 192.168.21.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2566/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2566/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3125/sshd
```

From the netstat manpage:

> You will also need superuser
>   privileges to see this information on
>   sockets you don’t own.

How do you know there isn't one running?  If the port is in use it makes sense that it would exit immediately with a 'socket in use' error.  what happens when you telnet to the port?

```
telnet localhost 5666
```

Answer (score 7):

execute 'netstat --tcp --udp --listening --program' as **root user**. other wise you it won't give **PID/Program Name**

then use kill -9 PID command

Answer (score 3):

I actually wrote a small shell script to help id these occassional questions:

```
#! /bin/bash
([ "$1" = "" ] || [ "$2" = "" ]) && echo "Usage: tracer <space> <port>" && exit 0
for i in `fuser -n $1 $2`
 do
  ps aux | grep $i | grep -v 'grep'
 done
```

save as /usr/local/bin/tracer; output:

```
root@mo-log:/usr/flows# tracer tcp 80
80/tcp:             
root     27904  0.0  0.0 111668  3292 ?        Ss   Aug04   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32324  0.0  0.0 335332  3560 ?        Sl   Aug05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32327  0.0  0.0 335324  3560 ?        Sl   Aug05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

You will need root privileges to use it

Comment: Good but I need more, I need to execute it for each connection in netstat. Then I can identify what a single program is doing. It's a box without lsof/fstat or other nice utilities, and as root I cannot install them because of other issues.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to track down the process by getting its inode via netstat and then using that inode with lsof. See my more detailed answer in https://serverfault.com/a/847910/94376.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, nfs related programs cannot be seen on the program list.

Also, LDAP pam modules and libnss_ldap open connections to ldap servers, but there is not an actual process holding the connection open, so netstat -tnp shows an active connection without a process.