# debian what's "-" process to listening on port 48296 to all ip?

Tags: debian-squeeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [netstat shows a listening port with no pid but lsof does not](https://serverfault.com/questions/311009/netstat-shows-a-listening-port-with-no-pid-but-lsof-does-not)

when i execute netstat -lntp in my server debian squeeze, i see one strange process... named - without pid,  and in listeing to port 48296, what this is?

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48296           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9350/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13377/apache2   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2315/sshd
```

how i can investigate better?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/311009/netstat-shows-a-listening-port-with-no-pid-but-lsof-does-not

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you're running `netstat` as root. Second, try using `lsof -i :48296` too see what does it say.