# getting rid of unused listening ports (kernel)

Tags: linux, nfs, linux-networking

As a follow-up on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/311009/netstat-shows-a-listening-port-with-no-pid-but-lsof-does-not), I have that issue *(ports that are reported listening in netstat, but have no process linked to it)* and it's the nlockmgr that's actually using these ports according to rpcinfo.

However, I cannot seem to get rid of these listening ports, even after unmounting nfs, stopping nfs-server, nfs-common, rpcbind ...

How can I get rid of these ports? (I don't require nfs on this server anymore)

Comment: Have you removed all the NFS related packages installed to the system?

Comment: of course,... but the clue is that the kernel seems to be keeping these ports open... even after unmounting all nfs mounts